# No file or directory on launch

Tags: ruby, net-sftp

I'm trying to make a proof of concept script with ruby, but seem to be failing...  I've give then script permission to run, but when it's ran I get ": No such file or directory" from my terminal.

I do have net-sftp installed through gem, so I'm at a loss as to what it could be.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'net/sftp'

Net::SFTP.start('10.0.0.8', 'jacob', :password=> 'password') do |sftp|
  #download a directory
  sftp.download!("/home/jacob/backups/*", "/home/pi")
end
```

Comment: do the folders `/home/jacob/backups` and `/home/pi` exist?

Comment: Yes, both of the folders exist.  I've even tried inserting puts "test" before the requre and the Net:: line, neither even gets a chance to run.

Comment: Can you please post the entire error message? If you are getting `bad interpreter: /usr/bin/env: no such file or directory` then it is not a ruby problem

Comment: That's actually why I'm so confused.  That is the entire error.

Comment: what is the output of `ls /usr/bin/env`?

Comment: Huh, well all I get is itself as a response... Weird it's worked in the past.  I'm guess I have an issue with my ruby install.

Comment: That output is fine. Are you perhaps using rvm or rbenv?

Comment: Can you run the script with `ruby <filename>`?

Comment: I'm not actually sure what that means.  I tried to run the file by typing ruby before the filename and that seems to work.

Comment: Hm. What happens if you type `/usr/bin/env ruby -v` directly at the command line?

Comment: ls: cannot access ruby: No such file or directory

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19911/discussion-between-jacobm001-and-padde)

Comment: did you type it with `ls` in the front? i meant just `/usr/bin/env ruby -v` by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with my system, not ruby.  Sorry for the confusion.